# MongoDB replica node become "(not reachable/healthy)"

Tags: mongodb, testing, jmeter, load, replicaset

In my current project we have 3 node MongoDB replica set setup (1 Master and 2 slaves) for document management service in production environment.
As the setup already existed, it was running correctly. There is a REST API end point which uploads the document to the mongo DB.
As we are required to do some performance testing with mongodb, I initiated the load testing via the JMeter and created a test plan which inserts data directly to the mongoDB by simulating 5 users.

All three nodes are up and running without any issues for short time period tests .
But ***when running the load test for long hours , one node becomes "(not reachable/healthy)"*** and elected the new PRIMARY within the other two nodes and load test runs without any issues and insert data using existing two nodes.

In development enviornment by removing the problem node and adding it as a new node did sync the data correctly and recovered as a secondary node.
But since these same configuration exists in the production environment we really need to know what cause the one node to become "(not reachable/healthy)".

Please note that in the current system we don't have enabled security and all three nodes runs in the same server with different port number with below config details.

**Node mongodb01**

[mongod.conf - will be the same for other two nodes with own dbpath, log path and port](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2MtBm.png)

**member details status**:

```
enter "members" : [
            {
                    "_id" : 2,
                    "name" : "<host>:27018",
                    "health" : 0,
                    "state" : 8,
                    "stateStr" : "(not reachable/healthy)",
                    "uptime" : 0,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(0, 0),
                            "t" : NumberLong(-1)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("1970-01-01T00:00:00Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39.870Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-11-09T03:07:38.381Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(300),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "Error connecting to <host>:27018 (10.103.58.45:27018) :: caused by :: Connection refused",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 21,
                    "configTerm" : 106
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 7,
                    "name" : "<host>:27019",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 1,
                    "stateStr" : "PRIMARY",
                    "uptime" : 498947,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1636435479, 10),
                            "t" : NumberLong(106)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39Z"),
                    "syncSourceHost" : "",
                    "syncSourceId" : -1,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "electionTime" : Timestamp(1636332442, 1),
                    "electionDate" : ISODate("2021-11-08T00:47:22Z"),
                    "configVersion" : 21,
                    "configTerm" : 106,
                    "self" : true,
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : ""
            },
            {
                    "_id" : 8,
                    "name" : "<host>:27017",
                    "health" : 1,
                    "state" : 2,
                    "stateStr" : "SECONDARY",
                    "uptime" : 99236,
                    "optime" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1636435479, 5),
                            "t" : NumberLong(106)
                    },
                    "optimeDurable" : {
                            "ts" : Timestamp(1636435479, 5),
                            "t" : NumberLong(106)
                    },
                    "optimeDate" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39Z"),
                    "optimeDurableDate" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeat" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39.371Z"),
                    "lastHeartbeatRecv" : ISODate("2021-11-09T05:24:39.371Z"),
                    "pingMs" : NumberLong(0),
                    "lastHeartbeatMessage" : "",
                    "syncSourceHost" : "<host>:27019",
                    "syncSourceId" : 7,
                    "infoMessage" : "",
                    "configVersion" : 21,
                    "configTerm" : 106
            }
    ],here
```

Answer (score 2):

`all three nodes runs in the same server` - very interesting setup, what are you trying to achieve here? The whole point of replication and master/slave setup is bypassing [single point of failure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_point_of_failure) constraint and in your case you don't get any benefit but just consume underlying OS resources, a single instance properly [tuned and optimized](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/article/performance-tuning-tips/) will work faster

Look at:

- MongoDB [log files](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/log-messages/), especially for the failing instance
- Operating system log files
- Operating system performance metrics (i.e. CPU, RAM, Disk, Network usage, etc.), it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test) as it might be the case one of your Mongo instances started consuming a lot of resources and has been terminated by [OOMKiller](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/153585/how-does-the-oom-killer-decide-which-process-to-kill-first)

Comment: Hi @Dmitri T,
thanks for your input, please note that in development environment we have the setup  with all three nodes in the same server , but we are migrating this to three different Linux VMs in production. Yes I know the replication does not benefit when it is in the one single server.
Thanks again I will analyse logs further and also will get the Jmeter plugin for system analysis.
n the problem node logs I can see the status as : "ctx":"ftdc","msg":"**serverStatus was very slow**"